# Parse list of json string using GSON

Tags: java, gson

I am working on a REST application and the response I get from the server is a string of Json with the following format:

```
[{"car": "ford"}, {"car": "nissan"}, {"car": "bmw"}]
```

I want to use Gson to retrieve information by key through each element in that list, but because it is returned as a string I'm not sure how to go about it.

If I simply had the response be:

```
String json = {"car:": "ford"};
```

Then I could retrieve the car's value as follows:

```
  Map<String,Object> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
  System.out.println( result.get( "car" ) );
```

But because the original string is a list of json's it's more difficult.

Help appreciated. Ideally still using the `Gson` class

Thanks

Comment: Are all your keys `car`? If so, does using a map make sense? This looks much more like a list of objects to me with each object having a car field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will helps you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    String log = "[{\"car\": \"ford\"}, {\"car\": \"nissan\"}, {\"car\": \"bmw\"}]";
    JsonArray jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(log).getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonObject)
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("car").getAsString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json string you have is actually an array. Try below:

```
  String json = "[{\"car\": \"ford\"}, {\"car\": \"nissan\"}, {\"car\": \"bmw\"}]";
  List<Map<String,Object>> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, List.class);
  result.forEach(l ->{
    l.forEach((k, v)->{
      System.out.println(k + ": " + v);
    });
  });
```